# Как работает forEach в javascript

Tags: javascript

Помогите понять как работает forEach  в js. Былоб хорошо наглядный пример. Одна и таже задача решённая с применением "for" и "forEach"
Спасибо

Отформатирую свой вопрос чтоб было более понятно. Спасибо за ответ тем кто ответил.
 Из-за чего возник вопрос. Я подумал как переписать это код используя forEach

```
 let length = 1;
    snake = [];
    for (let i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    }
```

И это оказалось совсем не так проосто как я думал. Поетому мне и нужен наглядный пример  с forEach и for  чтоб понять как работает. Буду благодарн

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration

Comment: forEach всегда обходит коллекцию начиная с начала. В твоем примере, ты обходишь коллекцию с конца, следовательно данное поведение нельзя реализовать с помощью forEach напрямую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `forEach()` выполняет указанную функцию один раз для каждого элемента в массиве.

```
arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
```

---

```
callback -
```

Функция, создающая элемент нового массива, принимает три аргумента:

```
currentValue
```

Текущий обрабатываемый элемент в массиве.

```
index
```

Индекс текущего обрабатываемого элемента в массиве.

```
array
```

Массив, по которому осуществляется проход.

```
thisArg
```

Необязательный параметр. Значение, используемое в качестве `this` при вызове функции `callback`.

---

Метод `forEach()` выполняет функцию `callback` один раз для каждого элемента, находящегося в массиве в порядке возрастания. Она не будет вызвана для удалённых или пропущенных элементов массива. Однако, она будет вызвана для элементов, которые присутствуют в массиве и имеют значение `undefined`.

---

Функция `callback` будет вызвана с тремя аргументами:

значение элемента (`value`)
индекс элемента (`index`)
массив, по которому осуществляется проход (`array`)
Если в метод `forEach()` был передан параметр `thisArg`, при вызове `callback` он будет использоваться в качестве значения `this`. В противном случае, в качестве значения `this` будет использоваться значение `undefined`. В конечном итоге, значение `this`, наблюдаемое из функции `callback`, определяется согласно обычным правилам определения `this`, видимого из функции.

Диапазон элементов, обрабатываемых методом `forEach()`, устанавливается до первого вызова функции `callback`. Элементы, добавленные в массив после начала выполнения метода `forEach()`, не будут посещены функцией `callback`. Если существующие элементы массива изменятся, значения, переданные в функцию `callback`, будут значениями на тот момент времени, когда метод `forEach()` посетит их; удалённые элементы посещены не будут.

---

```js
function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
  console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element);
}

// Обратите внимание на пропуск по индексу 2, там нет элемента, поэтому он не посещается
[2, 5, , 9].forEach(logArrayElements);
// логи:
// a[0] = 2
// a[1] = 5
// a[3] = 9
```

---

Еще пример:

```js
let arr = ["1", "2", "3"];

arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    alert(` ${i} : ${item} (массив: ${arr})`);
});
```

---

Последняя задача через `for` :

```js
let arr = ["1", "2", "3"];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  alert((` ${i} : ${arr[i]} (массив: ${arr})`));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, благодяря вам я разобрался

Answer (score 1):

ForEach принимает функцию итератора, функция итератора вызывается для каждой записи в массиве.

```js
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
a.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо,  за ответ  я вероятно не  совсем верно сформулировал вопрос меня интересует немного более расширено понимание работы forEach.  Так как  я столкнулся  с тем что не представляю как переписать  код где используеться for с помощью  forEach.  
    }

Comment: Для того, чтобы переписать код, нужно более полно привести изначальный код. А так получается snake.forEach(function(){})